# Parsing an xlsx file into a dictionary

Tags: python, excel, pandas, parsing, dictionary

I'm trying to parse a pretty simple `xlsx` file. It has 4 sheets in the following format: [lookup table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vslCI.jpg). I'm using pandas for this.

Here's what I want to do:

```
xls = pandas.ExcelFile('file.xlsx')
for sheet in xls.sheet_names:
    cur_sheet=xls.parse(sheet)
    cur_sheet=set_index(sheet)
    dic = cur_sheet.to_dict('index')
```

Problems:

1. Everything is in unicode, therefore has a "u" prefix, this will be problematic where comparing to other strings and setting values in the dictionary. I just can't get rid of it.
2. I want the dictionary to take only non Nan values
3. is there a pretty way to use "sheet" as the name of the sheet without having some counter? i.e:

   ```
   counter=0
   for sheets in xls.sheet_names
        cur_sheet=xls.parse(xls.sheet_names[counter])
   ```

Which I think is really ugly...

4. Ideally, I would like only one dictionary (first column is the same for all sheets)

I'm pretty new to Python and it's really nonintuitive to me. I've searched the web all day and can't really find normal workarounds.

Thanks!

Comment: ps. I want the left column to be the "key" for the dictionary (which is shared by all sheetS)

Comment: Really your question should focus on just one thing at a time. Point (3) is not really associated with your issue and is the only one I'd be confident to answer and get out of the way. Get rid of `counter` and just use `sheets` directly, though I suggest renaming it to `sheet` since it's singular and helps a bit with understanding. So, `for sheet in xls.sheet_names: cur_sheet = xls.parse(sheet)`.

Comment: point taken, I'll do that.
Regarding the counter issue. Your suggestion (and my first guess) will work for xls.parse, but won't work for cur_sheet.set_index(sheet). part of this is (my guess) that the sheet is read as u'Bla' and not just 'Bla' so it can't find it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets go one by one.
I recreated your *.xlsx* file as shown in picture and added a change to how you should read the file into pandas dataframe.
1.You could use [*applymap*](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) in following manner:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('expand_frame_repr', False)
dataframe = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx', sheetname = name, header = 0, index_col = 0) 
dataframe.applymap(lambda x: x.strip('u'))
```

It applies function that get rids of 'u' in every cell of dataframe,

2.[dropna()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) gets rid of NaN values.

3.And this is how you loop in pythonic way

```
xls = pd.ExcelFile('file.xlsx')
sheets = xls.sheet_names

for sheet in sheets:
     #your code
```

Lets combine it all together:

```
import pandas as pd
xls = pd.ExcelFile('file.xlsx')
sheets = xls.sheet_names
for sheet in sheets:
    dataframe = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx', sheetname = sheet)
    dataframe = dataframe.dropna()
    dataframe.applymap(lambda x: x.strip('u'))
```

4.I dont't really get the question so I can't help.

According to conversation in comments..

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx', sheetname = name, header = 0, index_col = 0)
cols = df.columns
the_list = list()
for col in cols:
    print(df[~df[col].isnull()].index.tolist())
    column = (col, df[~df[col].isnull()].index.tolist())
    the_list.append(column)
```

This code opens your file, then loops through columns and creates a tuple for each column containing column id and list of row id. So if you have x in columns 2_3 and row 3_0 the tuple will look like:  `('2_3', ['3_0'])`. Is this what you really want to do?

Comment: 1 doesn't help, I get this:AttributeError: ("'float' object has no attribute 'strip'", u'occurred at index 3_11')

Comment: Well you said you have 'u' everywhere so I assumed you have strings everywhere and error implies there are floats there too. So please clarify where exactly are those 'u's.

Comment: I have a pic attached of how my table looks like. "lookup table" in my first message. 'u's are for unicode format

Comment: Give me 5minutes I ll make exact same file you have and fix code.

Comment: Actually it should leave you with an empty dataframe since there is NaN in each row, you sure you used it like this: `df = df.dropna()` ?

Comment: Actually don't you want to get row and column for each x in your file?

Comment: It removes all rows... I just don't want nan's in my dictionary

Comment: It is not clear what your dictionary is supposed to contain.

Comment: no, this is just a mapping. later I will search with one of the col titles to get the matching row (or visa-versa)

Comment: {2_0:2_4, 2_1: 2_1, 3_0: 2_3......}
(that's why I also use the set_index)

Comment: You should really read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).
So in the end address is what you want for each x.

Comment: I added new code snippet check if this solves your problem.

Comment: Where exactly you have 'u'?

Comment: @NoaRegev There is no need, you're overthinking its importance. It doesn't exist as part of the string, it's _purely_ there in the printed form of the strings to indicate that it's unicode. That's all.

Comment: @NoaRegev try the following. Line 1: `a = 'hello'`. Line 2: `b = u'hello'`. Line 3: `print a == b`. It's `True`.